# How to calculate time and space complexity from a pseudocode?

Tags: time-complexity, pseudocode, mathematical-optimization

I am asked to determine use the time and space complexities of simple algorithms. The problem is that I don't fully understand where the numbers come from. From example we were provided it counts addition, subtraction, division, and multiplication as primitive operations.

Here I am posting pseudo code of my algorithm which calculates standard deviation by using formula we were provided.

I see 2 * (n - 1) addition symbols, 1 division symbol, 2 multiplication symbol and 1 subtraction symbol.

What else I must count here for time complexity? And what to do with space complexity?

```
// X is passed array, and N is number of elements in array.
Algorithm calculateStandardDeviation(X, N)
{
    private double arraySum;
    private double arrayMean;
    private double xi2;
    private double standardDeviation;

    foreach (arrayValue in X)
    {
        arraySum = arraySum + arrayValue;
    }

    arrayMean = sum / N;

    foreach (arrayValue in X)
    {
        xi2 = xi2 + Math.Pow(arrayValue, 2);
    }

    standardDeviation = Math. Sqrt(((1/N) * () * xi2) - Math.Pow(arrayMean, 2));

    return standardDeviation;
}
```

Comment: Look at the `for` loops, and especially the depth to which they are nested.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Algorithmic Complexity can, ironically, be as general or complex as you want. If you are working towards a big-oh O(...) notation complexity - as is the norm in computer science - @david robinson is correct with respect to your current situation.

A `for` loop generally adds a dimension of N time complexity - where N is the number of runs your loop contains. Everything else you do runs in O(1) "constant" time (*does NOT mean takes the same amount of physical time as another O(1) time op*). Therefore, your time complexity is the linear addition of all your operations or O(N + N + 1 + 1+...) = O(2N). This, i'm sure you learned in class, reduces to O(N). Time complexity.

Now for space complexity - same thing. Does anything grow as your input sizes grow? That would be a yes - your array grows as you add more elements to your array. Therefore it, too, grows as O(N). You have other constant space factors, but we're dropping that for big-oh, giving you

linear - O(N) - in time and space complexity.

Comment: But would you say that as `X` grows twice as large, the space taken up by the sum of its elements grows by the same factor? I don't think that's right.

Comment: No I would not, that's actually peaked at 2/4/8 bytes depending on the size you store it in. I only glanced at his code, did I miss something?

Comment: ok reading a little more carefully, still sticking with that - the array size grows as per your input growth. All the other factors remain relatively constant in size.

Comment: For some reason I thought that the space complexity of the `xi2` was nonlinear due to the  `arrayValue^2` term being added each iteration. I tested it in Python for `X` ranging from `[0]` to `[0...10000]` and the space complexity seems to be linear: http://i.imgur.com/vxo2v.png

Comment: Ah, no, unfortunately xi2 is stored in a "double" and is thus capped by the OS in terms of space. Your empirical results show excellent detective work though, would you like to edit my answer and add them in?

Comment: also +1 for using imgur even though I can't access it at work haha

Comment: It's just a perfectly straight red line in GNUPlot. If the code included `(arrayValue^2)^2`, the space would be quadratic.

Comment: @Blender hm. I tend to disagree. Do you mean the time complexity? Even so it would be a "constant" calculation as the value is read only once from the array. Space, however, must remain constant as the result is bounded by the OS in memory.

Comment: Python might be different. It dynamically allocates memory depending on the size of the object.

Comment: ahhh, good stuff, I had no idea that happened or was even possible! Stupid C blinders haha